# What is the status of this beta?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering what the status of this beta is?  Are we going to launch or are we going to fold (and our posts migrated)?

The drop off in activity can be explained as a sign that we need new members, i.e. go public.  With that in mind, wouldn't it be best to let the greater SE community decide, by their activity (or lack thereof)?

Comment: The drop in activity is pretty normal for two week betas. I don't think that we need to be too cncerned about it.

Comment: Yes, we definitely need new blood. Activity suggests we've somewhat tired, which is perfectly normal. More members, more activity, and now less active members will become more active too, because it gets more interesting. It's that simple. We've prepared the table, now we need guests so this feast can commence before the food gets cold. Open the doors! We'll serve desserts after the main course. ;)

Comment: Rather late to comment after 7 years, but the questions seems intersting still. Astronomy SE is still beta.

Comment: This could be closed now the site is no longer in beta.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pleased to announce that Astronomy (2.0) will be entering public beta this week.  We've been continually impressed with the enthusiasm here and have high hopes for this site to achieve Stack Exchange's goal to provide ["expert answers to your questions"](http://stackexchange.com/).  Overall with the response to the extra week in private beta has been encouraging and am looking forward to your progress in the next few months.

As the site goes public, think about who you might invite to participate in the site and think about the [7 essential questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).  On the main site, keep asking and answering the sorts of questions that will be interesting to knowledgeable astronomers either of the research or backyard variety.

Comment: Thank you for allowing us to continue on in the beta process. We won't disappoint.

Comment: This is great news (am having a very good day today) - this news, the news that I am cleared of cancer (Hve hd a scare for the past 3 months) and have got 2 more academic papers published.